# Working With Bluetooth printer Device

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

In my project need to search Bluetooth printer device and pared it and send text to printer

There is any API is available to search Bluetooth device and Pared and Sent text to particular
Device.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions:

#### is any API is available to search Bluetooth device ?

Please refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of API available on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=bluetooth%20serial&c=apps&hl=en). Personally, I like BlueSerial. Also you can use BluetoothChat sample code, it works too.

- Upload BluetoothChat sample codes to the device using Eclipse or Android studio
- Pair them
- Open BluetoothChat sample app
- Connect to BT device